# Prototype Inheritance Setup

Tags: javascript, class, oop, inheritance

I've probably read 15 different books, articles, or SO questions related to JavaScript Prototypal Inheritance and each had slightly different ways of doing things, so I wanted to get this figured out once and for all:

**Example**

```
function Rectangle(h, w){
  this.height = h;
  this.width = w;
  console.log("Rectangle ctor: "+ this.height + "x" + this.width);
}

Rectangle.prototype.getArea = function(){
  return this.height * this.width;
}

var a = new Rectangle(3, 4);

console.log(a.getArea());

function Square(l){
  this.height = l;
  this.width = l;
  console.log("Square ctor");
}

Square.prototype = new Rectangle();
Square.prototype.constructor = Square;

var b = new Square(5);

console.log(b.getArea());
```

This example works as expected. The Square object inherits from the Rectangle, therefore, it has the ability to use the `getArea()` method. However, there is 1 thing I always see being done differently depending on where I look.

Instead of doing `Square.prototype = new Rectangle()`, I have seen people use `Square.prototype = Object.create(Rectangle.prototype)`.  When I test this out, both appear to function in the same way, the only difference I notice is when I do this:

```
console.log(new Rectangle());
console.log(Object.create(Rectangle.prototype));
```

This logs the `new Rectangle()` which **includes** the `height` and `width` properties, then logs the `Object.create(Rectangle.prototype)` which logs the same thing except for the `height` and `width`.

So my question is, why do some people do it with one and not the other? Is one more beneficial than the other? The way I understand it, the one that uses `new Rectangle()` will get the height and width properties on its prototype which could result in issues, correct?

Can someone please shed some light on this? Thanks!

**EDIT**

I also realized that when using `new Rectangle()` as the prototype of Square, it actually calls the constructor (which may do something useful in some cases), whereas the `Object.create()` method does not.  Is the reasoning behind the 2 different usages related to the use case in terms of whether or not the constructor should be called to generate some object state that may be needed in the subtype?

Comment: Once and for all? Use ES6 `class` syntax.

Comment: Yes, but not all browsers can use ES6 yet and I am not using Babel at the moment. Plus its more about understanding whats going on under the hood that I am interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you answered your question yourself. The difference between `new Rectangle()` and `Object.create(Rectangle.prototype)` is that the former calls the constructor and the latter doesn't. Because of that, you should always use `Object.create()`. Otherwise the constructor will be called twice (as you can see in your example).

Also, in ECMAScript 6 you can use the [`class` syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes), which simplifies many things, like inheritance.

Comment: Ok thanks, I guess I am more trying to determine if one version is technically "deprecated" or if they are both completely valid depending on your use case.  After playing around with both, it appears that `Object.create(Rectangle.prototype)` is a cleaner way of doing things because you 1) Don't have to call the constructor an extra time and 2) You don't have prototype properties shadowed by the subtype objects (when using 'new', height and width get added to the `Square.prototype` which then gets shadowed by the this.height and this.width on the Square's constructor)

Comment: @MattHintzke IMO only the `Object.create()` option is valid.

Comment: @MattHintzke It's cleaner and less error-prone. `new` for creating prototypes is effectively deprecated, even when there are edge cases where it works the same.